# Lookup row in dataframe by truth testing of column of class list in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns such as:

```
> df
Col1     Col2
1,2,3    1
2,3      2
3        3
4        3
4,5      123
12       0
32       0

> class(df$Col1)
[1] "list"
> class(df$Col2)
[1] "integer"

>dput(df)
structure(list(Col1 = list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3), 3, 4, c(4,5), 12, 32), 
               Col2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 123L, 0L, 0L),..., class=data.frame)
```

How do I create a subset of df with only the rows where Col1 contains 2 or 3? IE:

```
> dfss
Col1    Col2
1,2,3   1
2,3     2
3       3
```

Thank you.

Comment: You _should_ have offered dput(df). Then the confusion about the content of Col1 would not have persisted. Your edit did not clarify that in the slightest.

Comment: Not really. The intent is to provide something that can be cut-pasted into an R session. I suspected that you had not done that because the spaces separating items in `df[1,1]` were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> df[ sapply(df$Col1,function(x) any(2:3 %in% x)) , ]
     Col1 Col2
1 1, 2, 3    1
2    2, 3    2
3       3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfss <- df[ grepl("2" , df[ ,1])| grepl("3" , df[ ,1]) , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In short words: check out `subset` and `grepl` if you are dealing with string.

Here is how I read your data and assume the value type is string, otherwise you can remove the stringsAsFactors and coerce it to whatever type you want.

```
> df <- read.table(text="
+ 1,2,3    1
+ 2,3      2
+ 3        3
+ 4        3
+ 4,5      123", col.names = c("Col1", "Col2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> # This is the key
> result <- subset(df, grepl("2", Col1) | grepl("3", Col1)) 
> df
Col1 Col2
1 1,2,3    1
2   2,3    2
3     3    3
4     4    3
5   4,5  123
> result
Col1 Col2
1 1,2,3    1
2   2,3    2
3     3    3
```

Comment: I too thought of this solution, but it fails in my real data frame. I have amended the sample data to better reflect why a simple grep does not solve. Maybe a more complex grep is the best way to go? Also, the data in Col1 are of class numeric.

Comment: The example has an incorrect representation of the data given that class df$Col1 was "list".